# D3.js and PHP: Draw graph limited by input constraints

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I have a list of constraints that are input by user in a HTML form and passed to a PHP page, as in this picture:

[image]

Each constraint is an array, containg all the x1,x2... values and the type of constraint (less than, equal or greater than), and the value of the right side after the constraint type.

How could I draw a graph based on those constraints with PHP, like the one in this picture: 
[image]

That is, I'd build a code to solve the equations separately and draw the solutions (results) as segments in the graph, creating a region limited by the segments, as shown in the second picture.

Is there a way to implement there with D3.js? I'm new with JavaScript but it seems this library is useful for it, but I'm totally lost, since I'm only finding things that are really complex, like plotting scatter plots with input data that contains hundreds of elements. Any help?

Comment: do you want to generate an SVG by PHP and show it on the HTML page or do you want the chart dynamic and respond to user changes in the form? Add a clip region for each constraint to multiple `g` elements.

Comment: I want to  to generate an SVG by PHP and show it on the HTML page. Do `g` elements refer to SVG? If so, when I combine PHP to SVG, does that mean that D3.js will no longer be necessary?

Comment: an SVG is just plain text, you can generate it with PHP if you know what it contains, you can use D3 to construct it and copy it from the DOM and use that as a template starter.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more thing, since I'm new in this specific subject, I didn't understan what `g` is, and "a clip region" is about D3js?

Comment: read the docs about SVG

Comment: Ok, thank you one more time!